# How can I use xmlstarlet and XPath to extract two elements at the same time

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

I have an xml document of the form

```
root
 +- foo
 +- bar
 |   +- @baz
```

I want to extract the value of `/root/foo` and of `/root/bar/@baz` in one go from the command line.

I can do

```
cat file.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/root/foo" -n
```

and

```
cat file.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/root/bar/@baz" -n
```

separately.

And I can do

```
cat file.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/root/foo|bar/@baz" -n
```

which gives me the value of `baz` *if `foo` doesn't exist*.

I tried

```
cat file.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/root/[foo and bar/@baz]" -n
```

but that doesn't work

```
compilation error: element with-param
XSLT-with-param: Failed to compile select expression '/root/[foo and bar/@baz]'
```

How can I get both?

**Update:** Minimum reproducible example

XML File

```
<root>
  <foo>Value F1</foo>
  <bar baz="Value B1" />

  <foo>Value F2</foo>
  <bar baz="Value B2" />
</root>
```

The command

```
cat file.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/root/foo" -n
```

Gives me

```
Value F1
Value F2
```

and

```
cat file.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/root/bar/@baz" -n
```

Gives me

```
Value B1
Value B2
```

and

```
cat file.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/root/foo|bar/@baz" -n
```

Also gives me

```
Value F1
Value F2
```

My expected outcome is something like

```
Value F1 Value B1
Value F2 Value B2
```

each in one line.

I am using `xmlstarlet`, version

```
1.6.1
compiled against libxml2 2.9.13, linked with 20913
compiled against libxslt 1.1.35, linked with 10135
```

I don't care which version of XPath I need to use to get this outcome.

Comment: While asking an XPath question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XPath expression that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XPath processor and its conformance with the XPath standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, or 4.0.

Comment: You say "I don't care which version of XPath I need to use to get this outcome." But xmlstarlet restricts you to 1.0. If you switched to Saxon's Gizmo [my company's product] you could use XPath 3.1, or even 4.0 if you don't mind being on the bleeding edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there with:

```
/root/foo|bar/@baz
```

try this:

```
root/foo|/root/bar/@baz
```

Answer (score -1):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v /root/foo[1] -o " " -v /root/bar[1]/@baz -n -v /root/foo[2] -o " " -v /root/bar[2]/@baz -n file.xml
```

output:

```
Value F1 Value B1
Value F2 Value B2
```